# How to Gain full Confidence in Pull Request builds

Tags: testing, code-reviews, test-coverage, production, pull-requests

Having confidence means Pull Request builds (in Jenkins) will finally allow you to merge the code after a Pull request builds successfully and is reviewed. You're 100% confident that it can go into production.

What are the measures(intermediate steps and best practices) a team should follow from the first step of recognizing an issue, then logging a JIRA, to finally merging the code after a Pull Request builds successfully?

What does a successful PR build convey about the code and what all it doesn't? How to make sure the things it doesn't cover are handled properly to gain 100% confidence that the code is production-ready?

Answer (score 1):

This question might be a bit too vague, but the answer is dependent on what your software is built on, what it does, and who your audience or customer base is.

Assuming your application has a client-side focus (in addition to server-side), having automation tests using testing frameworks such as Capybara that cover the majority of your customers common use cases will go a long way to prevent regressing functionality.

For server side-code, ensuring you have written the proper Unit tests for (almost) every line of code, and writing more extensive integration tests to cover (again) common use cases will prevent future bugs from cropping up. TDD is king in the modern era, but practicing TDD-lite (as I call it) can help you get on track pretty quickly (writing intended test cases first, and then fill in details as you code can work, but full TDD is preferred).

In both instances, when bugs crop up it's good to add tests for those bugs directly into your automation and unit test suites as to prevent them from regressing in the future.

These practices definitely requires something like Jenkins or other similar tools (Semaphore) to provide proper build statues.

To answer your question "What does a successful PR build convey about the code..." - the answer is, it should convey a general sense that your most common use cases and previous bugs have not broken or regressed. To help with this, providing steps for post-deploy to ensure everything works will help.

Doubling up on Code Review resources can help, but that is dependent on the individuals / team you have. But there should be rigor here (and there are plenty of resources around on opinions about how code reviews should work, this is one of my favorites: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6EzycFNwzY)

The following steps will be to QA said PR branch in a production identical environment that cannot affect customers (a QA or Staging environment works best, definitely spend resources getting this 1:1 to your production environment, doubly worth your efforts to use container software such as Docker as to not increase your server costs). Keep this branch isolated from your develop/master branch and only merge once it has passed CR, Build, and QA.

For you other questions about steps - I recommend laying out a solid foundation for how to write and groom both features and bugs. This involves your team following a good setup for JIRA tickets when issues/new features have been identified (providing accurate summaries of the problem or new feature, Steps To Reproduce, and any company specific details, and Demo steps for the developer to go through with Product, the Code Reviewer and the QA engineer), then providing good designs or solutions in the ticket before a developer picks up the issue (grooming). Grooming should help identify test cases.

I'm not sure how to measure this other than tracking tickets, tying new tickets to the tickets where they could have spawned and mapping out how many issues arise post release.

One more note: baking metrics into your code in advance will also help you keep your application in a state that you want and alert you to issues that may crop up where automation and previous steps have failed, allowing you to react faster to issues and provide a shorter time to resolution.